# Получение сум пар элементов

Tags: c#, linq

есть массив, например, 1 2 3 4 5 6. Нужно используя только методы расширения LINQ превратить его в массив 3 7 11. Если элементов нечетное количество, то элемент с последним индексом просто переносится.

Вообще вопрос общий. Суть - работа с элементами массива с учетом всего массива.

Comment: Не вполне понял, какой нужен результат для списка 1 2 10 (нечётное количество элементов).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ideone.com/jJcaqy

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        var res = a.Select((x, i) => new {x, i}).GroupBy(x => x.i >> 1, x=> x.x).Select(x => x.Sum());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", res));
    }
}
```

Но вообще, надо делать по-человечески руками в цикле.

Comment: круть. Я как раз нашел решение, только через Aggregate() вместо GroupBy() :)

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так сделать:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var transformedList = list.Where((item, i) => i % 2 == 0).
    Zip(list.Where((item, i) => i % 2 != 0), (first, second) => first + second).ToList();
if(list.Count%2 != 0)
    transformedList.Add(list[list.Count - 1]);
foreach(var item in transformedList)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: а в одну строку? Без If(***

Answer (score 2):

Практическое решение — воспользоваться пакетом [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var sums = list.Batch(2, batch => batch.Sum());
```

Этот код для случая нечётного количества элементов в последнюю сумму включает только один, последний элемент.

Если для нечётного количества элементов последний элемент не нужно включать в результат, необходим немного более сложный код:

```
var sums = list.Batch(2).Where(b => b.Count() == 2).Select(b => b.Sum());
```

Comment: ссылочку на море линки :)

Comment: @Grundy: Как раз добавил :)

Comment: А это решение обработает нечётное количество?

Comment: @ixSci: С последним обновлением — да :)

Comment: @ixSci: Хотя, может, я не понял вопрос. Сейчас уточню.

Comment: в последнем обновлении как раз отбросится последний элемент, а он вроде должен остаться

Comment: @Grundy: Расписал в решении, что делают оба варианта кода.

Comment: @VladD, если я буду писать для себя, обязательно воспользуюсь морем линков )). В случае же использования в продакшене, я не могу так поступить. Это же кто то будет поддерживать, поэтому такие вещи будут долго согласовываться и документироваться. Поэтому мне уж проще будет самому написать метод расширения дополнительный, или вообще через цикл i=i+2 пробежаться

Comment: @iRumba, вот через цикл и нужно пробежаться, а не мудрить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, на мой взгляд это интересная задача. Никто не заставляет вас над ней думать

Comment: @iRumba: Мне казалось, для продакшена как раз и характерно не выписывать затейливые велосипеды, которые позволяют сэкономить одну инструкцию на 100 элементов списка, в взять готовую библиотеку и не париться. Клиент ждёт, дедлайн на носу!

Comment: @iRumba, я вроде её уже решил и запостил ответ...

Comment: @iRumba: Ну зря вы так: если решение с циклом for короче и **проще**, чем с LINQ, то его и надо использовать, как мне кажется. (Но это _если_.)

Comment: @VladD, в данном случае, скорее всего, удобнее будет циклом. Хотя не факт, я уже имею 2 решения, свое и Qwertiy, так что возможно есть решение, которое выглядит лаконично и понятно. Я недавно работая с двумя массивами нагородил столько кода кода в цикле, что сам же там и потерялся. В результате написал одной строчкой линка (хоть и в 2 этажа) и она читается довольно легко, в отличие от цикла, выполняющего ту же задачу :)

Comment: @Monk: Ну я ж и пишу, что нужно предпочесть то решение, которое **проще**, а не то решение, которое с LINQ :) Если с LINQ проще, его и нужно предпочесть.

Comment: @VladD, к тому же скилл написания линков развивает и скилл их чтения. А это бесценный опыт )

Comment: @iRumba, всегда нужно помнить, что Ваш навык чтения LINQ может отличаться от навыка программиста, который будет читать Ваш код. Несколько этажей LINQ это ужасно для любого программиста, какой бы крутой квалификации он не был. Если появляются этажи, значит надо разбивать на переменные или даже функции.

Comment: @ixSci, 2 этажа - не смертельно. Скилл чтения линка нужен, чтобы не было программистов, чей навык написания выше. В этом случае я смогу писать читабельный линк, умело разбивать его на части и с большей долей вероятности быстро прочитаю линк, написанный другим программистом )

Answer (score 1):

Для полноты, вот ещё и ленивое решение с циклом.

```
static IEnumerable<int> ComputePairSums(IEnumerable<int> seq)
{
    int prev = 0;
    bool hasPrev = false;
    foreach (var e in seq)
    {
        if (hasPrev)
            yield return prev + e;
        else
            prev = e;
        hasPrev = !hasPrev;
    }
    // если нужно возвращать последний элемент для нечётного к-ва элементов, то:
    if (hasPrev)
        yield return prev;
}

var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var sums = ComputePairSums(list);
foreach (var v in sums)
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```